# How to force setup for checking whether prerequisite are installed?

Tags: c#, wpf, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have developed wpf application in C#. I have created setup project successfully. It is successfully installing the prerequisite. I have included MS Access 2010 redistributable as a prerequisite. First time the setup runs successfully. Then I remove it from Add/Remove Programs. It successfully get removed. But there is still MS Access 2010 redistributable present which does not get removed. I also don't want removal of MS Access 2010 redistributable. Second time when I run my wpf application setup, it asks for reinstall or removal of MS Access 2010 redistributable. This is I dont want. The setup should check wheather MS Access 2010 redistributable is installed or not. If not installed, install it. It installed then dont ask for reinstall or removal of MS Access 2010 redistributable. This is I want. How should I achieve the above task. Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue?

Comment: How did you make the installer? Visual Studio Setup Project? Did you use launch conditions or a bootstrapper (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link help you to define uninstall action where you could place code for mdac removal

under

```
public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
base.Uninstall(savedState);
}
```

in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx